# jQuery Validate - how do I use numberOfInvalids within highlight/unhighlight

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jQuery Validate and trying to use the example provided for invalidHandler in the jQuery doc that puts a message at the top of the page saying "You missed xxx fields, they have been highlighted".

Once you have validated the form once, the Validate plugin then validates individual fields on leaving the field. If the field is now valid, the highlighting on the field is removed, but the number of errors in the message box at the top is not refreshed, presumably because the invalidHandler is not called again.

Is there any way I can use the numberOfInvalids() function in the highlight/unhighlight function to update the error count there?

Or any other suggestion?

thanks, Kay

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I needed to declare a variable for the validation object,
  var validator = $("myForm").validate(
   ...
  }

Then I can use validator.numberOfInvalids()